# What is the use of Integer.Min_value in this code?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

What is the use of Integer.Min_value in this code? I know it is dereference S[top] for garbage collection, but need to know more about it

```
public int pop() throws Exception {

    int data;
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty.");
    data = S[top];
    S[top--] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You should clarify what you're asking for. This is generally done, as you've said, to allow the reference to be garbage collected (though if `S` is an `int[]` this isn't actually doing anything).

Comment: It's hard to say what use that value is, unless we can see what that method is used for. What class is it in? `pop` is a conventional name for a `Stack` type class, but unless we can see some context, I don't know how much help we can offer.

Comment: i am implementing the stack using array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a stack defined as an array such as this:

`S = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Stacks are last in, first out. The top variable should always be the index of the "last in" stack item, in this case `top = 4` because the last number in is `5` and has an index of `4`.

What this does is assign the content of `S[top]` to `data`, then assign `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `S[top]` to "clear" it, and then decrease top by 1.

This line:
`S[top--] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` can be rewritten as the following:

`S[top] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
top = top - 1;`

I think that the end goal is to clear old values in the stack and give them a default without having to resize the array.

Once the pop method has been executed, here's the result:
`S: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, -2147483648 ]` and `top: 3` and the "last in" item in the stack will be `4`.

Hope this makes sense.